# Will UICollectionView change the cell's selected property to true before sending didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, uicollectionview

The question is described above. Do I have to call UICollectionView's selectItemAtIndexPath method in the delegate method didSelectItemAtIndexPath, or does UICollectionView already did that for me?

Comment: The cell will be set to selected for you.  You do not want to call `selectItemAtIndexPath` from `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.  The select routine is used for triggering a selection without user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By the time `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is called, the selected property has already been set to `TRUE`.

To verify simply add:

```
NSLog(@"selected: %i", [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].selected);
```

to your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method and you will see it will come back `true` (1)

Answer (score 0):

There is a willSelectRowAtIndexPath method and a didSelect... method. The selection won't be changed when the willSelect... method is called, and **WILL** be changed on the did-select. (The willSelectRowAtIndexPath gives you a chance to change/cancel the selection before it occurs if you want to.)

This is a strong naming convention in the iOS frameworks. The tense of the verb in the method name tells you whether the event has occurred yet when the method is called (e.g. `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. The `viewWillAppear` method is called before a view is shown, and `viewDidAppear` is called AFTER the view is shown.)